# mysql why fields type of int have no length

Tags: mysql

I export a mysql schema from the server and import it to another server, but when I check the tables' schema, I found all int type fields have no length.

But when I tried to import it to my local mysql, It is all normal.

schema that has problem:

```
mysql> desc user;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| key        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| remark     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

schema on the local:

```
mysql> desc user;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| key        | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| remark     | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

mysql on the server is the official images of mysql of docker : `Server version: 8.0.21 MySQL Community Server - GPL`

my local mysql is install by homebrew: `Server version: 8.0.16 Homebrew`

Why dose this happen? And how to fix it?

Comment: Length option for INT datatype is fake option - so it was removed (parsed but ignored) in recent versions. If you need a value to be in some range only then use according CHECK constraint.

Comment: Why not share some of the code triggering that problem, such that others could see why this is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mysql manual says on [integer data type properties](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html):

> As of MySQL 8.0.17, the ZEROFILL attribute is deprecated for numeric data types, as is the display width attribute for integer data types. Support for ZEROFILL and display widths for integer data types will be removed in a future MySQL version.

Length property for integers did not restrict the value you couod store in an integer field anyway, it was used for display purposes only.